# Place UIView At Finite Location on Screen with UITableView

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I have a tableview that takes up more than the screen. Certain rows have an info button on them. When these are pressed, I want to give the user a message based on which row the info button was on. I want to show this message in a basic UIView that appears at the same spot on the screen every time (somewhat like a UIAlertView).

My problem is specifying the frame for the UIView so that it will show with the origin at a particular location on the screen. Trying to set the frame `self.view.frame` or `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` results in using the bounds of the whole scrollView or just the first visible element of the scrollView.

How can I make the view always appear in the same screen location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a static frame to your custom view. Like this

in didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod

try this code ----

```
UIView *infoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
UILabel *lblInfo = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,40,21)];
lblInfo.text = @"your text here";
[infoView addSubView:lblInfo];
[lblInfo release];
[self.view addSubView:infoView];
[infoView release];
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Unfortunately, that doesn't work: the infoView's origin goes to 10,10 in the scrollView's bounds. If the user has scrolled all the way tens of rows, and then presses one of the info buttons, the alertView shows up at the very top of the scrollView.

Comment: I told you this code for normal View for scrollview you can get scrollOffset from scrollview then create infoView frame according to that.

Comment: If you are using UITableViewController then change that to normal UIViewController and add TableView from interface builder.